# EntityFramework inserts and updates same time

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, entity

I am using Entity Framework 4 and when I am trying to update an existing record it updates and inserts a new record with the same values.

```
    public void UpdateEmployeeEvaluationResponse(long empId, long evalId, long QuestID, string responseStr)
    {
        var currentResponse = this.LoadResponseByEvaluationIdAndQuestionIdAndEmployeeId(evalId,
                  QuestID, empId);

      // response.ID = currentResponse.ID;
        //currentResponse.ResponseDate = response.ResponseDate;
        currentResponse.Response = responseStr;
      // entities.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(response).SetModified();
      // entities.EmployeeEvaluationResponses.Attach(response);
      //// entities.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(currentResponse, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
      // //entities.EmployeeEvaluationResponses.ApplyCurrentValues(response);

        ObjectStateEntry osmEntry = entities.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(currentResponse);
        osmEntry.ChangeState(EntityState.Modified);

      // //entities.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(currentResponse).SetModified();

        // //entities.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, currentResponse);
    //    entities.Detach(currentResponse);
       entities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

this is the implementation of the load method

```
    public EmployeeEvaluationResponse LoadResponseByEvaluationIdAndQuestionIdAndEmployeeId(long evaluationId,
                                                                                           long questionResponseId,
                                                                                           long employeeId)
    {
        return entities.EmployeeEvaluationResponses.Include("Employee").Include("Evaluation").Include
            ("QuestionResponse").Where(x => x.Evaluation.ID == evaluationId &&
                 x.QuestionResponse.ID == questionResponseId &&
                 x.Employee.Id == employeeId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Hi I solved it==> the problem was that from other uses there are some cached objects so
I made code to detach all objects and it works...Yeah... and another solution commented

```
   public void UpdateEmployeeEvaluationResponse(long empId, long evalId, long QuestResponseID, string responseStr)
    {
        foreach (var item in entities.EmployeeEvaluationResponses)
        {
            entities.EmployeeEvaluationResponses.Detach(item);
        }
        var currentResponse = this.LoadResponseByEvaluationIdAndQuestionIdAndEmployeeId(evalId,
                 QuestResponseID, empId);
        currentResponse.Response = responseStr;
        entities.DetectChanges();
        entities.SaveChanges();
        //using (AttendanceEntities entity = new AttendanceEntities())
        //{
        //    EmployeeEvaluationResponse responseObj =
        //        entity.EmployeeEvaluationResponses.Where(x => x.Evaluation.ID == evalId &&
        //            x.QuestionResponse.ID == QuestResponseID && x.Employee.Id == empId).FirstOrDefault();

        //    responseObj.Response = responseStr;
        //    entity.DetectChanges();
        //    entity.SaveChanges();
        //}
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the implementation of LoadResponseByEvaluationIdAndQuestionIdAndEmployeeId method as I think it contains problem

Comment: Is table EmployeeEvaluationResponses has 3 foreign keys for other 3 tables Employee & Evaluation & Questionresponce .Please make sure the relation between these 4 tables are mapped correct.

Comment: yes it is mapped correct